# How do I control the size of protocol header/message in Scapy?

Tags: python, zeromq, scapy

I'm trying to create the ZMTP protocol for Scapy but can't find how to effectively pad a field and the packet up to a certain byte size.

I've tried creating the Greeting message described here, https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/863889/ZeroMQ-Diving-into-the-Wire, as a new protocol in Scapy:

```
class ZmtpGreeting(Packet):
    name = "ZMTP Greeting"
    fields_desc = [
        XByteField("signature", "ff00000000000000117f"),
        XByteField("version_major", "03"),
        XByteField("version_minor", "00"),
        PadField(XByteField("security_mechanism", "4e554c4c"), 20, padwith="\x00"),
        XByteField("as_server", "00"),
    ]
```

**Problem 1:**
The above implementation doesn't seem to include the padding up to 20 bytes for the security_mechanism field:

```
###[ IP ]###
  version= 4
  ihl= None
  tos= 0x0
  len= None
  id= 1
  flags=
  frag= 0
  ttl= 64
  proto= tcp
  chksum= None
  src= 1.1.1.2
  dst= 1.1.1.1
  \options\
###[ TCP ]###
     sport= 1111
     dport= 2222
     seq= 1
     ack= 1
     dataofs= None
     reserved= 0
     flags= PA
     window= 8192
     chksum= None
     urgptr= 0
     options= []
###[ ZMTP Greeting ]###
        signature= ff00000000000000117f
        version_major= 03
        version_minor= 00
        security_mechanism= 4e554c4c
        as_server= 00
```

This entire packet should also be padded to 64 octets and I'm not sure how to include that in the protocol (or as padding outside of it).

**Problem 2:**
I am unable to use raw(..) or len(..) because they fail with the following error:

```
fields.py in addfield(self, pkt, s, val)
    138         `pkt`) to the raw string packet `s`, and return the new string packet.
    139         """
--> 140         return s + struct.pack(self.fmt, self.i2m(pkt, val))
    141
    142     def getfield(self, pkt, s):

error: required argument is not an integer
```

**Problem 3:**
This is in its own python file under layers, but only works when I directly paste it into the Scapy console.

I've been looking through the documentation for Scapy but there haven't found out how to achieve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have all the same problems with the simple Disney example here: https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_dissect.html

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *how to effectively pad a field and the packet up to a certain byte size.*

On `python` side, you can always `import struct` and operate using all of its bit-fields' manipulation, using the **`<mask>`**-meta-language controlled smart-mappings of values onto the resulting bit-field (in any of both ways using `{.pack()|.unpack()}`-methods) as in `struct.unpack( aMSG_STRUCT_MASK, aMSG )`

A "hierarchical" (step-wise) assembly might be needed, if partial checksums are to be used in the game of making the final ZMTP:RFC-compatible packet-payloads.

This includes several code-paths for potentially version-specific payload-assembly handling rules, set from different ZMTP:RFC versions/releases/modes-of-operations.

Perhaps start with pencil and paper, to sketch all the bit-fields details, as required by the ZMTP:RFC and check all theirs implementations ( This is a brutally manual method, yet this inventory + checklist can literally save you as the last-resort because it works and is damn methodically orthodox - unchecked mandatory requirements mean "forgotten" part of the implementation + incompatible/wrong implementation can be tested feature by feature, so no one is ever left unchecked or ill-validated ) - this might sound boring, but is a life-saving habit.

> **Q** : ***Problem 2:***

is undecideable as not being reproducible, yet further debugging efforts will show the root-cause ( trying to add a **`<pyObject>s`**, using a **`+`**-operator, to a **`<pyObject>`**-yielded from a call to the above recommended tool, the **`struct`**-package `.pack()`-method:
 **`struct.pack( self.<anInstanceAttributeMASK>, self.<aMethod>( <pyObject>, <pyObject>) )`**

> **Q** : ***Problem 1:*** 64-octet padded / word-aligned / null-terminated

All these requirements, controlled by the detailed ZMTP/RFC-specifications are to be met, and `struct.pack()` will meet these, given just properly set **`<aPackMASK>`**-s will participate on a ZMTP-payload-content packet-data assembly.

Best review, whether all of the ZMTP:RFC specified details ( lengths, alignments, paddings, terminations, (partial)checksum(s) ) are indeed met (even for corner cases) and correct/modify all features found to have been missed.

---

In case large-integer elements fail to get processed by formatting, one may always split the large block into a series of a few, smaller ones, to circumvent any potentially failing `int/string` operations on formatting/packet assembly in any part of the ScaPy hard-coded functions, as show here:

```
|>>> sig_num= 0xff00000000000000117f
|>>> sig_num
1204203453131759529496959L
|>>> "{0:x}".format( sig_num )
'ff00000000000000117f'
|>>> "{0:b}".format( sig_num )
'11111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000101111111'
|>>> len( "{0:b}".format( sig_num ) )
80
|>>> "{0:0>20b}{1:0>20b}{2:0>20b}{3:0>20b}".format( sig_num / 2**60,
                                                    sig_num % 2**60 / 2**40,
                                                    sig_num %         2**40 / 2**20,
                                                    sig_num %                 2**20
                                                    )
'11111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000101111111'
```

Comment: This is a really detailed answer, but it falls a bit short when it comes to Scapy and how to actually implement the protocol :/

Comment: @Cukic0d I dare say it addresses the O/P-s concerns with how to successfully (re)engineer the ecosystem of ZMTP::RFC-defined behaviours (first) if trying to re-interpret all, there defined features and distzributed-behaviours' components, inside the ScaPy packet assembly/disassembly framework. Without using the 1:1-fit of the original-system, no emulated would ever match the original. In that light one ought read the steps addressed above. Well-crafted emulation, meeting the 1:1-fit with the original, is worth doing all the steps properly. The rest is but a waste of own time and resources :o)

Comment: Thanks for both your replies. If I understood you correctly, you're recommending a byte-based approach to constructing frames that Scapy could send. Is that correct? My goal is to do some conformance testing around the ZMQ implementation and my use of it to see how it behaves in response to invalid/modified messages. The first idea I had was to build a python test application using Scapy. Another one is to find a TCP repeater and manipulate it on a byte-level before forwarding the message.

Comment: @Pazow Well, not exactly, I try to make you **augment ScaPy** with smart-"segmented" byte-fields processing in those places, where the current ScaPy methods fail to process "large"-ints within its standard fields' processing ( as was demonstrated in the O/P posted Traceback ) Using the manually-crafted mappings is a circumvent strategy for those methods, that fail. **Anyway**, keep us posted about your **conformance-tester-Project ... sounds great and usefull**

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, in Scapy, a `X[...]` field is only for user-friendliness. This means that you can't use a string as a default value: Scapy only works with ints (except for special fields, packet fields, string fields...). Updating those values to the numeral representation will fix Q2
- I doubt the ByteField can take such a high value :/
- to add the final padding, have a look at `post_dissection`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think you're correct in that the field does not seem to take all of these octets. Even though I've changed from string to hex values, I get an "argument out of range" error. Removing PadField didn't help either: XByteField("security_mechanism", 0x4e554c4c)

Comment: That's the second point: a byte field can take values up to 256. You probably don't want to use this. Check the RFC, it's more likely an int or something.

Comment: Yes, the RFC describes it as a null padded string. Is the equivalent in Scapy a Raw layer instead?